# Microsoft Outlook change e-mail display back to cards

Tags: outlook, office365

I find it very hard to describe the problem other than with screenshots, therefore I proceed to ask this question.

Until today, my Outlook PC Application (Office 365) looked something like this screenshot I found on the web.

[image: Outlook screenshot from https://office365.4team.biz/sync-outlook-between-devices.aspx]

Notice the e-mails are displayed as "cards" showing the sender, subject, date and priority.

But as of today, I find that first only in my inbox, later also in all other folders across all of my mail accounts, the display has changed to a reduced table view with much more information. See the following screenshot for reference.

[image: Screenshot of my own Outlook inbox]

I searched for over an hour and did not find a corresponding setting anywhere that changes the table / column display back to cards. I tried the outlook options and every single option in the view tab.

**EDIT: On the right side of my screen, I have the reading pane active - it was just not contained in the screenshot. I updated the screenshot to show that it's active.**

Does anyone know how this comes to be without me changing anything, and especially how to change it back to "cards" display? Thank you in advance.

Comment: is it a programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like you turned off the reading pane and so the "cards" have gone away and now you just have the single line layout.

If that's the case, you should be able to select "View" on your top ribbon, then select the "right" option under the "reading pane" button so the reading pane returns.

You did already mention trying everything under the view tab, but as far as I can tell, it will switch from the "cards" display to the single line layout in your screenshot if the reading pane is disabled. The cards also return if you simply reduce the horizontal width of your window, so this appears to be a dynamic design choice that Outlooks prefers if the cards reach a certain width.

Additionally, under “View Settings”, “Other Settings” you can select between the compact layout and single line layout. The compact layout is the one you want.

[screenshot of outlook reading pane option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaKt3.png)

Comment: Sorry my screenshot didn't make that clear as I didn't want to disclose too much information - but on the right of the mail list, I have the reading pane active for the selected mail, exactly using the option you described. However the display of the mails in the list itself does not change regardless of if I enable or disable it. (I just updated the screenshot in the question). Also, the width of the mail list column sadly does not change the display mode of the mails, however slim or large I make them... And lastly I also tried zooming with CTRL or the controls on the bottom right, no change

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying that! In that case it may simply just be the width of the reading pane is too narrow and that's causing the emails to switch to this different display format. You can try widening the reading pane to see if it causes the format to change.

When widening and shrinking the reading pane my outlook dynamically switches between the two formats in your screenshot.

Comment: I think I can remember that my outlook also used to do this back in the day - however regardless on how wide or narrow I have all areas, nothing changes in the display of the mail list itself...

Comment: Within the view tab there is gear on the left to select "View Settings", and in that list you can select "Other Settings" - you can deselect "Use compact layout..." and instead select "Always use compact layout" - does that option return the cards the way the were before?

If it's instead set to "Always use single-line layout" it will look as you've shown regardless of the width.

Comment: Wow ... you made my day! That worked like a charm, now the mails look the same again.  Also, I only had to change this setting once, and it worked directly on all mailboxes ... Thank you so much!

Comment: glad we found the solution!